# ¿Porque me da el error [object NodeList]?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando que nada mas seleccionar un radio button se guarde en una variable en php, pero por ahora solo e conseguido realizarlo en javascript y me da el error [object NodeList].

```js
function updateTotal() {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('shipping');

    document.getElementById('prueba').innerHTML = radios;

}
```

```html
<strong>estado</strong> = frio
<label>
    <input name="shipping" type="radio" id="RadioGroup1_0" value="calor" checked="checked" onclick="updateTotal()" />
</label>calor
 <input type="radio" name="shipping" value="frio" id="RadioGroup1_0" onclick="updateTotal();" />
 <br />
 <span id="prueba">aaaa</span>
```

Comment: Hola Kaiserdj, no necesitas colocar tu código en jsfiddle, lo deberías colar directamente acá e incluso hacerlo ejecutable

Comment: Por cierto no hay nada de PHP en tu código, si lo que quieres es que se actualize el span `prueba` al hacer clic en alguna opción, eso se hace totlamente en el lado cliente con JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByName(name)` retorna un array de elementos(NodeList) con el nombre indicado(que en tu caso serian 2).

Supongo que lo que quieres es imprimir el valor del `radio` seleccionado y para eso debes de buscar el elemento que tenga la propiedad `checked` igual a `true` y luego obtener la propiedad `value` del mismo:

```js
function updateTotal() {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('shipping');

     for(var i = 0;i < radios.length;i++)
     {
        if(radios[i].checked)
        {
         document.getElementById('prueba').innerHTML = radios[i].value;
        }
     }

   

}
```

```html
<strong>estado</strong> = frio
<label>
    <input name="shipping" type="radio" id="RadioGroup1_0" value="calor" checked="checked" onclick="updateTotal()" />
</label>calor
 <input type="radio" name="shipping" value="frio" id="RadioGroup1_0" onclick="updateTotal();" />
 <br />
 <span id="prueba">aaaa</span>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me fue de gran ayuda, y para hacer esto mismo en php, ¿es complicado? Mi intención es guardar el valor seleccionado en una variable php